# Что возвращает метод bs4 find_all? В документации написано возвращает список. Питон пишет class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
url = 'https://www.oreilly.com/radar/'
res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,'html.parser')
print(type(soup.find_all('title')))
# <class 'bs4.element.ResultSet'>
```

Comment: ResultSet это и есть список

Comment: Судя по исходникам, it depends. В каких-то случаях возвращается прямо вот список, а в каких-то `ResultSet`. При этом, класс `ResultSet` унаследован от `list`, поэтому разницы особой нет.

Comment: ResultSet - это класс отнаследованный от list: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vgy0H.png Source: https://git.launchpad.net/beautifulsoup/tree/bs4/element.py#n2419. Сделано так видимо для отлова ошибок, когда к списку результатов пытаются обратиться как к одном результату (AttributeError): `ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?`